# OpenGL bitmap fonts

Tags: c++, c, opengl, шрифты, bitmap

Здравствуйте! Прочел обалденный туториал по bitmap-шрифтам от NeHe. Но к сожалению, тот код работает только на Windows. Как можно сделать тоже самое как [здесь](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bitmap_fonts/17002/), только также для Mac и Linux?

Comment: Там внизу же есть ссылки с портами под разные платформы от фанатов этого туториала.

Comment: К сожалению, там используются SDL, SFML и т.д. Мне нужно обойтись без них.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достань нужные функции и радуйся.

Cсылка на порты от  [Nehe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/bitmap_fonts/17002/)